# kill default gallery process android

Tags: android, process, kill

how can i kill a specific task on android?
i want to kill default android gallery task for refresh it for add and know my new image's that i make those programmatically in my app. i found below code on stackoverflow but i do'nt know how use it for kill Default gallery App on My Smart-Phone.

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
actvityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packagename);

android.os.Process.sendSignal(pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);

android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);

actvityManager.restartPackage(packagename);
```

is there a way for refresh galley by code?

Answer (score 1):

I would broadcast this intent instead:

[ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)

```
Broadcast Action: 
Request the media scanner to scan a file and add it to the media database.
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to kill the process to refresh the gallery.

You can apply scanner to refresh gallery.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { path }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            // Gallery is updated 
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks , this code need unimplemented method , what's that? and that is path on code?